# unable to connect oracle with laragon

Tags: oracle, laragon

I have enabled oci8 in php.ini file. 
[php ini snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAtGJ.png)
and this give me call to undefined function.
[error snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCzRW.png), please help.

Comment: Please post [text instead of images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45632830/edit) and add [properly formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Don't add new information, particularly anything that needs to be formatted to be readable, as comments.

Comment: `extension=php_oci8_12c.dll   
extension=php_openssl.dll  
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll  
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll  
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll  
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll  
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll  
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll  
extension=php_pgsql.dll  
;extension=php_shmop.dll `  in my php ini file and it gives error  Call to undefined function Yajra\Pdo\oci_connect()

Comment: i am new in stack overflow. I am learning, line break  not working.

Comment: My previous comment included a link to the help centre article on formatting your question. But four spaces at the start of each line to treat it as code.

Comment: Thanks.  For your suggestion.